# What does '< >"' '"</>' mean in PHP?

Tags: php

My code look something like this:

```
   echo '<pre>"';
   echo str_pad("Hello, world !", 26);
   echo '"</pre>';
```

Why does PHP uses this ugly syntax for inserting tags inside single and double quotes ? Does it have a special meaning ?

Comment: For php everything in quotes is nothing more than a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: have you tried to echo it? if you did, please post output in comment.

Comment: you can also use echo "<pre>\""; The escaped " won't end the string but will be printed out.

Comment: Did you read PHP's manual?  It's all in there.  Pretty early on in fact, as I recall.

Comment: You should read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for strings.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes indicate that what is between is a string, rather than, for example, a comparison operator or a division operator.

The double quotes on lines 1 and 3 are literal double quotes as part of the output.

The output of this will be:

```
<pre>"Hello, world !            "</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of above code will be

```
<pre>"Hello, world !           "</pre>
```

The double quotes are outputted!

Generally though, enclosing a string in single quotes `'` prevents PHP from parsing the string for replacement variables while with double quotes `"` variable names are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This is because they are meant for different things.

```
<?php
echo 'Something $variable1 \n'; // Will output `Something $variable1  \n`
?>
```

---

```
<?php
$variable1 = 'asd'
echo "Something $variable1"; // Will output `Something asd`
?>
```

---

`'` basically says DON'T INTERPRET ANYTHING INSIDE, JUST OUTPUT IT.

`"` will interpret anything inside.

If you want to add `'` or `"` inside a string that is enclosed by them, you need to scape them:

```
<?php
echo 'I want \' my semicolon to appear'; //will output: `I want ' my semicolon to appear`
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a string. Any thing between " " or ' ' is treated as a string.